# AC stops working in 2002 Pontiac sunfire SE 2002 at high RPM

Tags: ac, pontiac, sunfire

I have a 2002 Pontiac sunfire SE. The ac works when I drain the Freon and refil it. It works better on high way. But there’s this weird thing that happened twice. I reved it to a high RPM (like 4000-5000).  Then the ac completely stops working, blowing like a fan. Then again when I drain the Freon and refill it, it works. I have no idea what’s going on

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Once it gets above the RPM level, it just keeps working no matter what RPM level the engine is at?

Comment: It's a V5 or CVC compressor. Check if the clutch hub on the compressor's pulley is still rotating after you make it cease operating the way you described (revving high). If so, the mechanical control valve on the compressor's body might be faulty.